# Collecting Containers metrics and Hostsystem metrics with node-exporter?. How can I do this?

Tags: windows, docker, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

My hostmachine is a windows system and I'm running docker desktop. I've running prometheus / node-exporter / cadvisor and grafana in a container.
Currently I get only the metrics of the containers, not from the windows host system.
How is it possible to collect data from host system?
There is a simular question in Stackoverflow but this not work for me, probably it's for a linux host system.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060894/how-to-resolve-prometheus-node-exporter-node-filesystem-device-error-within-do#:~:text=To%20emit%20host%20filesystem%20metrics%20from%20within%20a,so%20it%20knows%20where%20to%20find%20the%20filesystems.](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Here is my compose-file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  prometheus:
    container_name: Monitoring-Prometheus
    image: prometheus
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    volumes: 
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - ./prometheus_db:/var/lib/prometheus
      - ./prometheus_db:/prometheus
      - ./prometheus_db:/etc/prometheus
      - ./alert.rules:/etc/prometheus/alert.rules
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--web.route-prefix=/'
      - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=200h'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    ports:
      - '1840:9090'
    restart: unless-stopped

  node-exporter:
    container_name: Monitoring-Node-Exporter
    image: node-exporter
    ports:
      - '1841:9100'

  cadvisor:
    container_name: Monitoring-Cadvisor
    image: cadvisor
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    ports:
      - '1842:8080/tcp'
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      -  /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro

  grafana:
    container_name: Monitoring-Grafana
    image: grafana:latest
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    ports:
      - "1843:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./grafana_db:/var/lib/grafana
    depends_on:
      - Monitoring-Prometheus
    restart: always

  reports:
    image: skedler
    container_name: Monitoring-Reports
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
      - reportdata:/var/lib/skedler
      - ./reporting.yml:/opt/skedler/config/reporting.yml
    ports:
      - '1844:3001'

networks:
  monitor-net:
    name: monitoring-network
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  reportdata:
    name: reports-data
    driver: local
```

here my prometheus.yml file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'Monitoring'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus' 
    static_configs: 
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:1840']
  - job_name: 'node-exporter' 
    static_configs: 
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:1841']
  - job_name: 'cadvisor' 
    static_configs: 
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:1842']
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run your exporters directly as Windows processes to get metrics from your host. Otherwise, containers are running in a Linux hypervisor, and that's what you'd be getting metrics from with `host.docker.internal` references.

Comment: Hi OneCricketeer, yes you're right. When I'm running node-exporter/prometheus in my host environment, I'll be getting the host data. But is it not possible to run node-exporter in a container and collect metrics from the container AND from the host?

Comment: If you run it as a container, then you need to consider what it thinks is a "node". On Linux hosts, it'll run as a cgroup process. On windows, that's a hypervisor, not Windows OS.